# How to trigger Jquery in Nintex form Sharepoint?

Tags: jquery

I borrowed the following jQuery from [here](https://community.nintex.com/t5/Nintex-for-SharePoint-Forum/How-to-check-if-a-Date-Time-falls-within-a-range-and-avoid/td-p/19333/highlight/true/page/3). The code is supposed to create  validation in a Nintex Form before it is submitted and check if dates booked for the same Car already exist in previous entries in the list to avoid double booking/overlapping. However I'm not familiar on how to get it to trigger what CSS values should be updated in the form . Any help is appreciated.

```
var allItems = [];
var listName = 'P...Car Request'
NWF$(document).ready(function() {
retriveListItem();
NWF$('select[name*="DateHours"],select[name*="DateMinutes"],input.nf-date-picker').change(function() {
checkOldEntries();
});

});

function retriveListItem() {
    NWF$.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=*,PoolCar/CarRegistration&$orderby=FromDate&$expand=PoolCar&$top=5000",
        type: 'GET',
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
                var item = data.d.results[i];
                item.sDate = getDateLocalFormat(item.FromDate,-5);
                item.eDate = getDateLocalFormat(item.UntilDate,5);
                allItems.push(item);
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
};

function getDateLocalFormat(inputDate,min) {
    //var add_10_minutes_to_current_date = Date.dateAdd(new Date(inputDate), -5, "h");
    return Date.dateAdd(new Date(inputDate), min, "m");
    //return new Date(inputDate);
};

Date.dateAdd = function(currentDate, value, timeUnit) {
    timeUnit = timeUnit.toLowerCase();
    var multiplyBy = {
        w:604800000,
        d:86400000,
        h:3600000,
        m:60000,
        s:1000
    };
    var updatedDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + multiplyBy[timeUnit] * value);
    return updatedDate;

};

function checkOldEntries() {
    //var count = 0;
     var allBookings='';
    var enteredSDate = new Date(ddmmyyTommddyy(NWF$('#' + validateFromDate).val()) + ' ' + NWF$('select[name*="DateHours"]:eq(0)').val() + ':' + NWF$('select[name*="DateMinutes"]:eq(0)').val());
    var enteredEDate = new Date(ddmmyyTommddyy(NWF$('#' + validateUntilDate).val()) + ' ' + NWF$('select[name*="DateHours"]:eq(1)').val() + ':' + NWF$('select[name*="DateMinutes"]:eq(1)').val());
    if (!(enteredSDate === undefined) && !(enteredEDate === undefined))
        NWF$.each(allItems, function(i, v) {
               if(v.PoolCar.CarRegistration == NWF$('#' + validatePoolCar).val().split('#')[1])
               {
                    
            if (((enteredSDate > v.sDate && enteredEDate < v.eDate) || (enteredEDate > v.sDate && enteredEDate < v.eDate) || (enteredSDate > v.sDate && enteredSDate < v.eDate)) || (enteredSDate <= v.sDate && enteredEDate >= v.eDate) ) {
                       if(allBookings==''){
                            allBookings='The selected pool car '+v.PoolCar.CarRegistration+' is already booked on \n';
                       }
                        allBookings+='\n'+dateFormatddMMyyyyHHmm(v.sDate) +' >> '+dateFormatddMMyyyyHHmm(v.eDate);
                  console.log(v);
               }}
        });
          if(allBookings!=''){
                allBookings+='\n\nPlease choose a different date.';
               alert(allBookings);
               allBookings='';
          }
          
          
          
};
function dateFormatddMMyyyyHHmm(inputDate) {
    var d = new Date(inputDate),
        dformat = [ 
                    d.getDate().padLeft(),(d.getMonth()+1).padLeft(),
                    d.getFullYear()].join('/')+
                    ' ' +
                  [ d.getHours().padLeft(),
                    d.getMinutes().padLeft()].join(':');
                         //,d.getSeconds().padLeft()].join(':');
                         return dformat;
};
function ddmmyyTommddyy(inputDate) {
    var dateS = inputDate.split('/');
    return dateS[1] + '/' + dateS[0] + '/' + dateS[2];
};


Number.prototype.padLeft = function(base,chr){
   var  len = (String(base || 10).length - String(this).length)+1;
   return len > 0? new Array(len).join(chr || '0')+this : this;
}
    
$('#showit').click(function(){
   
     $('#result').html(dformat);
});
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.